# How to add another layout number of time to my already created LinerLayout?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-emulator, layout-inflater

Here is my Prent layout (main.xml)

```
<!-- ============================================================ -->
            <!--  All Employees are added here (added and More then one) -->
            <!-- ============================================================ -->
            <LinearLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/myLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000">

                <!-- ++++++++ here extra layout is added programmatically -->


            </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my another layout file that I want as child, say child.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"         
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"         
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"         
    android:gravity="center_vertical"         
    android:orientation="horizontal" >          

    <Button             
        android:id="@+id/btn_left"             
        android:layout_width="100dp"             
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:singleLine="false"   
        android:maxLines="2"         
        android:text="hello"/>
    <TextView             
        android:id="@+id/list_title"             
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"             
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
        android:layout_weight="0.5"             
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"             
        android:text="Photos"             
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />          
    <Button             
        android:id="@+id/btn_right"             
        android:layout_width="100dp"             
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
        android:text="Save" />     
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in my Main activity I am calling the main.xml and based on the for loop condition I want to add the layout of the child.xml and every time I want to set the different value of the TextView of child.xml

So how it is Possible?

I have done like this:

```
private void doCalculationForMultipleEmployee() {
    singleEmployee.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    for (int i = 0; i<=tempEmployerList.size()-1; i++) {  
        View repeatedLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.test);     
        ((TextView)repeatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_title)).setText("Employee"+i);     
        // customize repeatedLayout with other data     
        myLinearLayout.addChild(repeatedLayout);
    }
}
```

But after doing that I got syntax error at .inflate and at .addChild

So where have I gone wrong? Please help me by some code to add it by for loop.

Comment: i think you should use listview

Comment: Probably you need a ListView and not a LinearLayout. See here for more info http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a loop like below:

```
    LinearLayout parent=findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
       LinearLayout llItem=(LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.createFromSource(R.layout.child, null);
       TextView txt= (TextView)llItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
       txt.setText(list.get(i));
       parent.add(llItem);
    }
```

Comment: `parent.add(llItem);` doesn't compile for me ==> the `LinearLayout` doesn't have any definition for `add()` but for `addView()` .

Comment: For me the layout is being inflated in the same line...I need it line by line...can u help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Inflate the view then add to the parent

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
Layout child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout2, null);
TextView title = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
parent.addView(child);
```

Repeat as many times as necessary or use a loop

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly you need to display button, textview and button side by side in your layout.
If you want this you just take listview and use custom adapter, with this you can display button, text and button side by side